# Render MediaStream into a WebGLRenderer

Tags: javascript, three.js

This might seem really odd, but how do you render a video stream

```
var videoStream = new MediaStream(stream.getVideoTracks());
```

into a

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true});
renderer.setSize(640, 480);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an official example that demonstrates how to apply a media stream (from a webcam) to the video element of a [THREE.VideoTexture](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/VideoTexture). The important bit is:

```js
if ( navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ) {

    var constraints = { video: { width: 1280, height: 720, facingMode: 'user' } };

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( constraints ).then( function ( stream ) {

        // apply the stream to the video element used in the texture

        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();

    } ).catch( function ( error ) {

        console.error( 'Unable to access the camera/webcam.', error );

    } );

} else {

    console.error( 'MediaDevices interface not available.' );

}
```

Full example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_video_webcam